# IOS sudzc arc empty second response, first works without problems

Tags: iphone, ios, sudzc

i'm using the generated acr code from sudzc in my iPhone project. i already imported the missing h files, fixed the body tag and everything works fine...for the first call of any function.
i call the functions in several positions in my code like in the viewDidLoad:

```
TestWsdlService_ManagerService* service = [TestWsdlService_ManagerService service];
 [service getAttended:self action:@selector(getEventsHandler:) email: @"testmail@bla.com" password: @"testpass"];
```

first call works well. logging is enabled so i see the correct post and the correct response.
when i call the same functions again, i only see the correct post but it gives me that error with an empty response (no xml, nothing):

```
2012-08-14 10:26:55.574 Test[1768:11603] nserror Error Domain=CXMLErrorDomain Code=1 

"Unknown error" UserInfo=0x6e5fea0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error}
2012-08-14 10:26:55.580 Test[1768:11603] Error: Unknown error
```

i also tried it with a singleton like this:

```
static TestSoapSingleton *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (TestSoapSingleton *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.manager = [TestWsdlApi_ManagerService service];
        self.manager.logging = YES;
        self.username =@"testmail@blub.com";
        self.password = @"test pass";
    }
```

but at the end i got the same error.
the error is thrown in the CXMLDocument.m in the initWithData function, because the inData is empty (size=0).
also in the SoapRequest.m in the connectionDidFinishLoading function, the receivedData is empty.

i tried to debug the SoapRequest.m and detected, that the didReceiveResponse is called in the first and the second call of a function, but the didReceiveData is only called at the first time.

if i do two method calls right behind each other like this:

```
TestWsdlService_ManagerService* service = [TestWsdlService_ManagerService service];
     [service getAttended:self action:@selector(getEventsHandler:) email: @"testmail@bla.com" password: @"testpass"];

TestWsdlService_ManagerService* service2 = [TestWsdlService_ManagerService service];
     [service2 getAttended:self action:@selector(getEventsHandler:) email: @"testmail@bla.com" password: @"testpass"];
```

it also works without problems.

hope anybody has a solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

after several hours i found the bug...webserver problem / session problem. got issues with the zend::auth adapter
but i wonder why the ksoap2 api is working with the session things and the nsurlconnection not^^